# calculating standard deviation results index exceeds matrix dimention error

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

i am calculating standard deviation of 250x250 image but i am getting following error
can anyone help please..

```
  210.2683
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> test at 5
std1=std(g(:));
```

my code snippet is

```
  kl=imread('ai427.jpg');
  g=rgb2gray(kl);
  M=mean(g(:));
  disp(M)
  std1=std(g(:));
  disp(std1)
```

i dont know what the error is and how to resolve it(i mean how i will get the result )

any help is appreciated.....

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the image to `double`,

```
  g=double(rgb2gray(kl));
```

then check that you haven't used the word `std` before as a user variable or function, Or add `clear std` before that line and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate standard deviation of `250x250` image, you can also do the follwing:

```
kl=imread('ai427.jpg');
g=rgb2gray(kl);
M=mean(g(:));
disp(M)
std1=std2(g);
disp(std1)
```

Comment: FYI, `std2` computes the standard deviation of the array A using `std(A(:))`.

Comment: Yes. I know. Thanks though.